# Use an async call is the same of using a synchronous call in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm using boost and would like if this:

```
// --- some random function ---
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock;
char b[256];
// connect and stuff here
boost::asio::async_read( sock,
    boost::asio::buffer(b, 256),
    boost::bind( &onRead, _1, _2)
    );
```

is the same of

```
// --- some random function ---
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock;
boost::thread *read_thread;
char b[256];
// connect and stuff here
read_thread = new boost::thread( 
    boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &( io))
    );
io.post( &read, b, sock);


// --- read function
bool read( char b[], boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock){
    boost::asio::read( sock,
        boost::asio::buffer(b, 256),
        boost::bind( &onRead, _1, _2)
        );
}
```

I just would like what happens in an async call and what it differs from a sync.

Edited:
My main question is: the async call blocks the thread binded with the io_service?

Edited 2:
This solved my issues: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-async/?ca=dgr-lnxw02aUsingPOISIXAIOAPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A synchronous call returns when it has performed its work, and the result of the work is available in the next statement. Such a call may very well *block*.

An asynchronous call returns immediately, but the state of the work is indeterminate. When the work is done, the registered call-back function is called by the ioservice, and since you're running that service in a separate thread, the call-back runs in that separate thread, too.

Asynchronous programming is much harder in terms of the control flow, but it is vastly superior in terms of performance. If the reads and writes are part of the ongoing operation of the server, then you're almost always better off with an asynchronous model (though this may well be single-threaded, just not with Boost). Simple tools that run once and do a bunch of things in a sequence, on the other hand, may just use synchronous calls, which is simpler to write and understand and might not make a difference if you need to wait for the result of the operations anyway.

Comment: But, the async call blocks the thread binded with the referent io_service?

Comment: @lucastamoios: No, it doesn't. The ioservice itself implements single-threaded asynchronous operations and a polling loop. Only when an operation has finished does the call-back execute, non-blockingly but sequentially in the ioservice thread.

Comment: so, there is a invisible thread in my application??? It was what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @lucastamoios: No, the thread is not invisible. It's right there in your code! The call-backs are run from the `run()` function of the ioservice.

Comment: What I mean, there is some thread that handle the async function, before the callback execution, for example, in a async_read function, there is some place where read is been processed, so, when it finishes, the callback binded in async_read function is called. Isn't it?

Comment: @lucastamoios: The read is asynchronous, so the `async_read` function returns immediately. Asynchronous I/O is an operating system feature, and there is no user code involved in actually reading bytes from the device. Just think of an epoll event loop (which is what Boost.Asio is).

Comment: Could you show me some place where I can learn more about it? I mean, about async as a OS feature... Thanks since now by all those answers, it was really enlightening! (: